# Cannot Install the forked repo as dependency in the package.json

Tags: git, github, npm, node-modules

I have an issue with installing my forked repository as a dependency.

Here start with I forked [repository](https://github.com/agneym/playground) (agney/playground) and later on, my forked repo will name `my-user-name/playground` and I want to install the forked repository as a dependency in the `package.json` of another project.

I tried many approaches but failed

- Add `"xxx": "git+https://github.com/my-user-name/playground.git"` into `package.json`. Got an error `Can't add "xxx": invalid package version undefined.`
- Write `npm install my-user-name/playground#master`in the terminal and got an error `Can't install github:my-user-name/playground#2d9fe8394108c1c63298e109289c72fc3bc56291: Missing package version`

Please someone tell me the solution or approaches to fix this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by adding a version to forked repo.